# How to ignore missing components in list unity 2020?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image: Missing(game object)]

**How to ignore these missing elements?**

or

**How to remove my destroyed target from the list?**

```
public class SkinMananger : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject[] characters;
    public int selectedCharacter = 0;
    public GameObject carrot;

    public void NextOption()
    {
        characters[selectedCharacter].SetActive(false);
        selectedCharacter = (selectedCharacter + 1) % characters.Length;
        characters[selectedCharacter].SetActive(true);
    
     
    }

    public void BackOption()
    {
        characters[selectedCharacter].SetActive(false);
        selectedCharacter--;
        if(selectedCharacter < 0)
        {
            selectedCharacter += characters.Length;
        }
        characters[selectedCharacter].SetActive(true);
      
    }

    public void PlayGame()
    {

        PlayerPrefs.GetInt("selectedCharacter", selectedCharacter);
      
    }

}
```

and I use `Destroy(gameObject);` for my characters when certain actions take effect. So I need a skin manager to work also when they are destroyed. As at this moment, it stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Linq `Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where) and the [implicit `bool` operator](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-operator_Object.html) like e.g.

```
using System.Linq;

...

public void RemoveInvalidEntries()
{
    characters = character.Where(c => c).ToArray();
}
```

This basically equals doing something like

```
var list = new List<GameObject>();
foreach(var c in characters)
{
    if(c) list.Add(c);
}
characters = list.ToArray();
```

---

Alternatively I usually prefer a dedicated class that keeps track of existing instances itself like e.g.

```
public class Character : MonoBehaviour
{
    private readonly static List<Character> instances = new List<Character>();

    public IReadOnlyList<Character> Instances => instances;

    private void Awake ()
    {
        instances.Add(this);
    }

    private void OnDestroy ()
    {
        instances.Remove(this);
    }
}
```

so later you can go through

```
Character.Instances
```

and be sure that in that list always only currently existing instances are registered.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a check for null reference inside your function :

```
  public void NextOption()
  {
      if(characters[selectedCharacter])
      {
          characters[selectedCharacter].SetActive(false);
          selectedCharacter = (selectedCharacter + 1) % characters.Length;
          characters[selectedCharacter].SetActive(true);
      }  
  }
```

You can do same in BackOption() function just surround it with the same If condition. It checks whether characters[selectedCharacter] is null or not. If its null it just simply ignores. But you need to make sure that selectedCharacter variable is always greater than length of array otherwise array out of bounds error will occur.